# android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, centos, android-espresso

I try to run UI tests on a headless jenkins (on centOS)  and I get this error:

```
    Starting 6 tests on test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2
com.MobileTornado.sdk.newclient.screens.login.MessageScreenTest > LimitMessage[test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2] [31mFAILED [0m
    android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.MobileTornado.newclient:id/chatTab

com.MobileTornado.sdk.newclient.screens.login.MessageScreenTest > SendMessage[test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2] [31mFAILED [0m
    android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: com.MobileTornado.newclient:id/chatTab

com.MobileTornado.sdk.newclient.screens.login.MessageScreenTest > zzz_signOut[test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2] [31mFAILED [0m
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException''. Check device logcat for details
Tests on test10_googleAPIs(AVD) - 4.1.2 failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'
:new-client:connectedDevDebugAndroidTest FAILED
```

Jenkins start to do the tests and then failed!

I run this tests on android studio and also with jenkins on windows- and all the tests pass!

The emulator run (but I didn't see it, it's a headless machine) because before I get:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5786 wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim
[android] Emulator reported that the startup process is 'running'
```

Use:
 Android Studio project, gradle 3.3,espresso 2.2.2

What is the problem?